# Why is there a minimize button in the Unity Dashboard?

Tags: 11.10, unity, unity-dash, minimize

If you launch the Unity Dashboard, there are the traditional 3 buttons in the top-left-hand corner. They look (something) like this:

```
X ― □
```

The X closes the dash.
The □ either maximizes or minimizes the dash, depending on it's current state.
The ― does..

..What exactly?
I know it's faded out, but couldn't it have the same function as close, or almost the same but have the dash fold into the top-left-hand corner?

Note: I always have my dash maximized, so to me they are the close, minimize and minimize button. Please use the symbols, so i know which one you mean.

Comment: Huh this is strange? The - button on my machine does nothing but gaining brightness with every time I click it and goes to nearly zero brightness when i move the mouse away from it. Anyone else have the same behaviour as I observe?

Comment: I've noticed that too. I think it's how the buttons are supposed to look when you click on them, but is acting weird because this one doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was changed to be like this [by design.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/838875) I don't have access to the document listed there which discusses the design, but I'd imagine it's preferable to disable one of the three buttons rather than remove it. This gives a more consistent look across the system.

There are a couple bug reports citing this [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/862775) and [here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/867910) It was also brought up [in this mailing list.](https://lists.launchpad.net/ayatana/msg06337.html)

The brightness bug has been reported [here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/871327)